# Ruby: using a hash to access instance methods

Tags: ruby, hash, instance

I'm working on a problem in Chris Pine's *Learn to Program* book. I've defined a class `Pet`, with some instance methods. Outside of the class definition, I'm trying to build a method that will take a string and an instance of the `Pet` class and run the appropriate instance method.

```
def dispatch(command, pet)
  dispatches = {'feed'       => pet.feed,
                'walk'       => pet.walk,
                'put to bed' => pet.putToBed,
                'rock'       => pet.rock,
                'toss'       => pet.toss}
  dispatches[command]
end
```

When the `dispatch` method runs, however, it executes all the instance methods that appear in the hash, not just the one corresponding to `command`. They execute in the order they appear in the code, and before even reaching the `dispatches[command]` line.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: give the class body also.. so that we can run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is correct behaviour.

```
{'feed'       => pet.feed}
```

The line above means "call method `pet.feed` and use its return value for assigning to key 'feed'". You have to use lambdas (or similar) to create chunks of code that can be invoked later. Something like this:

```
def dispatch(command, pet)
  dispatches = {'feed'       => proc { pet.feed },
                'put to bed' => proc { pet.put_to_bed }}
  dispatches[command].call
end
```

Comment: I don't understand,why there is a need of `lamda`.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. I was pretty sure it was calling each method as the hash was being populated, but forgot exactly why. Variables and objects, as usual :)  Thanks!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I don't understand,why need `lambda` ? Without `lambda` it works..:)

Comment: @Arup Rakshit - it works either way in terms of the value returned, but with the `lambda` it *only* calls the desired method of Pet. This might be important if the methods did anything other than return a value.

Comment: @NeilSlater still I am not clear. Probably OP should ask the question more properly... :)

Comment: @Arup Rakshit: If you have set up an example, add a `puts` into each target method, and imagine that the OP only wishes to see a single `puts` output. Or imagine that the method calls are commands to a robot, and you only want to execute one of them.

Comment: @ArupRakshit If `class Pet` contains `def feed; print "feed "; end` and `def put_to_bed; puts "put_to_bed"; end`, the above procs are changed to `pet.feed` and `pet.put_to_bed` and `.call` is removed, then `dispatch('put_to_bed', Pet.new) => feed put_to_bed`.  I'm sure you know that, so I suspect there may be a misunderstanding about what OP was saying.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I got your point and @@Neil's point too...thanks for your times to clear the things.. :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit I expect the OP was referring to what the dispatch method was doing, whereas you were considering what it was returning.

Answer (score 1):

While creation of the hash all methods are evaluated. I advise to read about the use of the method `send` (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-send) If you use `send` you will end with something like:

```
def dispatch(command, pet)
  pet.send(command)
end
```

Note that you will need to adjust the name of the method `putToBed`.

Comment: I'm afraid, `send` won't do for OP. If you review sample code, you'll see that he is trying to use string `"put to bed"` to call a method. That string is no valid method name. Apparently, this is part of some kind of human-friendly interface.

Comment: It would be easy to transfer "put to bed" into "put_to_bed" or "putToBed" (what btw is a bad method name), I think...

Comment: But what about `"go to sleep" => pet.put_to_bed`? How do you transform that? :) That's why it's good to have mappings. So that you don't leak your implementation details to the user.